# Check if a date column is in a range of dates - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, calculated-columns

I have to check if a date column is in a range. In particular I have to check if it is included in a range given by another date +/- n days. Suppose my dataframe is:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {
'date1': ['2019-09-11', '2019-09-12', '2019-08-02'], 
'date2': ['2019-10-11', '2019-09-24', '2019-11-11']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I have to chek if (date2 - 5 days) < date1 < (date2 + 5 days)

Answer (score 16):

Use [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) with add and subtract 5 day timedelta with filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
d = {
'date1': ['2019-09-11', '2019-09-12', '2019-08-02'], 
'date2': ['2019-09-14', '2019-09-08', '2019-11-11']
}
#changed data for match
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print (df)
        date1       date2
0  2019-09-11  2019-09-14
1  2019-09-12  2019-09-08
2  2019-08-02  2019-11-11

c = ['date1','date2']
df[c] = df[c].apply(pd.to_datetime)

a = df['date2'] - pd.Timedelta(5, unit='d')
b = df['date2'] + pd.Timedelta(5, unit='d')

df = df[df['date1'].between(a, b, inclusive=False)]
print (df)

       date1      date2
0 2019-09-11 2019-09-14
1 2019-09-12 2019-09-08
```

Another solution with [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df = df.query('@start < date1 < @end')
print (df)

       date1      date2
0 2019-09-11 2019-09-14
1 2019-09-12 2019-09-08
```

Comment: I'd like to give your profile introduction a +1 too if I could

Comment: @kerwei - Not necessary. Btw, if check my profile, do you think code for email is stupid? My idea is prevent contact me people not ask about pandas.

Comment: @kerwei - Thank you.